# Android Calendar.getTime().getTime() always returning -1 day

Tags: android, date, datetime, calendar, timezone

I creating calendar instance by providing timezone and then setting day, month and year to calendar. But when I am trying to gettime in millisecond then it always returning dateTime in millisecond **-1 day**.

Here is How I am setting Calendar.

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()), R.style.DialogTheme, (view, year, month, dayOfMonth) -> {
        Calendar calendar = new DateUtils().getCountryCalendar();
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, (month));
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        long selectedDate = calendar.getTime().getTime();
    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
```

I am setting bu it returning me **selectedDate** as **1624986000000** which is **Tue Jun 29 2021 22:30:00**

Here is getCountryCalendar() method.

If I am selecting 30th June then it should return 30th June in millisecond. I don't know why it's happening. Any suggestion are appreciated.

```
public Calendar getCountryCalendar() {

    return Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Bangkok"));
}
```

Comment: A midnight at UTC+7 timezone is still the previous day at UTC <7. How are you printing out the date that comes out? Where does the 22:30 come from?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate`, `Instant` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: There is no such thing as *30th June in millisecond*. A millisecond value defines a point in time, and at that point it is two, occasionally three different days in the different time zones on Earth.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate
.of( y , m , d )
.atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Bangkok" ) )
.toInstant()
.toEpochMilli()
```

## *java.time*

The modern solution uses the *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the legacy date-time classes such as `Calendar`.

Build your date-only value.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( y , m , d ) ;
```

Apparently you want the first moment of the day in that date as seen in a particular time zone. Do not hard-code a time of 00:00:00.0. That time of day may not exist on some dates in some time zones. Let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Bangkok" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Apparently you want to convert that to a count of milliseconds from the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 as seen in UTC. The `Instant` class represents a moment as seen in UTC.

```
long millis = zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp `1624986000000` indeed is `Jun 30, 00:00:00` by `Asia/Bangkok` time zone. You can even check it [here](https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1624986000000).

On the other side, Colcata and Colombo timezones render this timestamp as `Jun 29 2021 22:30:00`.

Since you haven't shared the code where you convert timestamp to 22:30:00, my assumption that in that piece of code you are not using the right timezone (but rather `Asia/Colcata`, or `Asia/Colombo`, or something else that matches `GMT +05:30`)